# Issue with shifting paste data when I copy row from 1 sheet into another

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA script. My objective is to copy a row of data from one workbook from a hidden Sheet name "Tracking" and post the row into another workbook sheet name "PDOTracking"

I want the user to point to the row to be pasted and click paste, but when I do this each time after the first, the data is shifting to the left and falling out of line with the columns.

This is my script

```
Sub CopyRow()

        ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("Tracking").Visible = True
        Sheets("Tracking").Select
        Range("$A$6:$Hy$6").Copy
        Sheets("Tracking").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Keep in mind, when copying, I do not want the user to see the sheet being copied from, hence I want it to stay hidden.

Its the paste step that is an issue.

Comment: re: *'Its the paste step that is an issue.'* Oddly enough you seem to have omitted that step from the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub CopyRow()
    dim dr as long
    dr = activecell.row
    workSheets("Tracking").Range("$A$6:$Hy$6").Copy _
        destination:=activesheet.cells(dr, "A")
End Sub
```

If you don't want the user to see the sheet, don't make it visible. There is nothing from stopping you from copying data from a hidden worksheet.

BTW, to remove the worksheet from the list of hidden worksheets that the user can make visible, make the Tracking worksheet xlsheetveryhidden.

```
worksheets.visible = xlsheetveryhidden
```